# Iterate to every element of the multidimension array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, xml-parsing

I have a array i getting through an xml .i want to iterate every element to the array which is hash and get the every hash element value using key.
I want to someting like this>>

array>>

```
education_split = [{"University"=>"Institute Of Engineering And Emerging Technologies", "Degree"=>"MBA", "Year"=>"2007"}, {"University"=>"H.N.B. Garhwal University", "Degree"=>"MSC", "Year"=>"2005"}, {"University"=>"H.P. University", "Degree"=>"Med", "Year"=>"2003"}, {"University"=>nil, "Degree"=>"12th", "Year"=>"1999"}, {"University"=>nil, "Degree"=>"10th", "Year"=>nil}]
```

now i want to iterate to every element of the array and get the value of university ,degree,year in iteration. something like that..

```
 education_split.each do |edu|
     //here are some other things also like creating object
      edu["University"] 
      edu ["Degree"] 
      edu["Year"]
   end
```

This is also working but in some cases it is though error >> TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer)

here all fields are string and values i am getting are also string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to check a hash :

```
education_split.each do |edu|
     //here are some other things also like creating object
  if edu.is_a? Hash
      edu["University"] 
      edu ["Degree"] 
      edu["Year"]
  end
end
```

Reading the error, I am sure your collection `education_split` contains also *arrays* with *hashes*. Now to prevent the error and as you interested only to hash that part of the code, just do a check if `edu` in any particular iteration, *is a hash* or not. if *hash*, do your operation or skip it.

*TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer)* only comes, when you would try to get array elements using *strings*, instead of *integers*. Like `a = [1, 2]`, and now do `a['x']`, and see you would get the exact error you are now getting.

Comment: +1 for explaining TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer)

Comment: Yes actually this is the issue but i want to convert this array into hash format and save into the data base.

Comment: @Mayank That seems to be a different question. Ask it differently, as your current post don't have any clue to help you.

Comment: Actually this is the response i am getting through some external api as xml and i am converting xml to save into data vase that's why in some cases i am getting correct format as hash but some cases i am getting this error..is there any to handle such cases

Comment: is there any to convert hash to single element arry like converting {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3} to [{"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}]

Comment: @Mayank very simple `[ hash ]`.. :)